# Angular Dynamic forms patchValue doesn't work for checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GQqlKvw65yS1G48WmP0e?p=preview) with this issue. This plunker is based on [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) angular dynamic forms example:

I have tried to patch this form with some model as shown in the screenshot below, here the code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
    this.form.patchValue({
      emailAddress: 'test@test.com',
      agree: true
    })
  }
```

As you can see the email address field is patched fine, but for some reason checkbox is not initialising its value.

[image]

Can't find any bug with this description online.

Any idea?

Comment: I replaced `[type]="question.type"` with `type="checkbox"` https://plnkr.co/edit/aqYGDBrHsjMsw28XSgEu?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui that works indeed. Thanks for releasing me from pain. :)